# Reducing memory usage for FizzBuzz in R

Tags: r, fizzbuzz, memory-optimization

I've been trying all night to get my fizzbuzz to use below 20 MB of RAM but I can't seem to get it much smaller than this.

```
# Sample code to read test cases
args <- commandArgs(trailingOnly=TRUE)
test.cases <- strsplit(readLines(args[[1]], warn=FALSE), '\n')
args <- NULL
for (test in test.cases) {
    if (length(test) > 0) {
        # ignore test if it is an empty line
        # 'test' represents the test case, do something with it
        test <- as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(test, " ")))
        x <- 0
        y <- 0
        for(i in 1: test[3]) {
            if(i != 1) cat(" ")
            flag <- TRUE
            out <- i
            x <- x + 1
            y <- y + 1 
            if( x == test[1] ) {
                cat("F")
                x <- 0
                flag <- FALSE
            }
            if( y == test[2] ) {
                cat("B")
                y <- 0
                flag <- FALSE
            }
            if(flag) cat(out)
        }

        cat("\n")
    }
}
```

Comment: I was able to resolve it by simply removing the assignment of out <- i

Comment: Welcome to CodeReview, DaveGerson.

Comment: Your code does not create any significant data other than the one read through `readLines` so it is unclear what the problem is. I really doubt that removing `out <- i` is really what made a difference. It is not one variable holding an integer that will make a difference.

Comment: I think it has something to do with how code-eval calculates memory.  It seems like all assignments are added to the memory usage for the algorithm. I've tried destroying objects throughout the code in order to lessen the total memory usage but it doesn't have any effect.

Comment: the inputs here are a string like the following "x y z".  x in this case is fizz,  y is buzz,  and z is how high you count to.

Comment: @flodel 
Sorry for the confusion.  Code-eval is a hackerrank/leetcode/topcoder style challenge site. The challenge I was working on is their version of fizzbuzz.  The stdin is a series of 20 seperate lines with about 3 ints per line, separated by a space.  The actual challenge link is below [challenge](https://www.codeeval.com/open_challenges/1/ )

Comment: FYI, I went on that website and played enough with it to come up with this conclusion: the way it computes RAM usage cannot be trusted. Your code or my code should use nowhere near 30mb for the input sizes they are being provided. Not even near 1mb. I suspect it is including the RAM required to make a R process run (I loaded R and checked with top: my version of R under mac OS requires 34mb), which seems unfair. Using that website to learn about R seems a bit like a waste of time if the performance metrics are so wrong.... On the other side, I hope my answer taught you something.

Comment: I found that other (unanswered) thread casting doubts about how Code Eval measures memory usage:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27794368/what-is-making-my-code-use-so-much-memory that

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for providing the link, it helped a lot in understanding what you were after. I will provide two versions for you to consider. The first one is algorithmically similar to yours, except written a little more in the "R style". The second one will make a more efficient use of memory since that seems to be important too.

I will also assume that the input file in `args[[1]]` is like the one in the link, i.e. contains lines like the two below:

```
3 5 10
2 7 15
```

**Version 1:**

```
args <- commandArgs(trailingOnly = TRUE)
input.file <- args[[1]]
test.cases <- strsplit(readLines(input.file, warn=FALSE), ' ')
for (test in test.cases) {
   stopifnot(length(test) == 3L)
   XYN <- as.integer(test)
   X <- XYN[1]
   Y <- XYN[2]
   N <- XYN[3]
   i <- seq_len(N)
   is.divisible.by.X <- (i %% X) == 0L
   is.divisible.by.Y <- (i %% Y) == 0L
   out <- as.character(i)
   out[is.divisible.by.X & is.divisible.by.Y] <- "FB"
   out[is.divisible.by.X] <- "F"
   out[is.divisible.by.Y] <- "B"
   cat(out, sep = " ")
   cat("\n")
}
```

Some noticeable improvements are:

1. some assumption checking with `stopifnot`
2. the use of variable names that are closer to the problem write-up (`X`, `Y`, `N`) or more descriptive, e.g., `is.divisible.by.X`
3. the use of `%%` for finding if a number is divisible by `X` or `Y`
4. vectorization (notice how one of your `for` loops is gone), which should make your code faster
5. The use of `seq_len(N)` instead of `1:N` is more robust in the case when `N` is zero.

---

**Version 2:**

```
args <- commandArgs(trailingOnly = TRUE)
input.file <- args[[1]]
file.handle <- file(input.file, open = "r")
repeat {
   line <- readLines(file.handle, n = 1)
   if (length(line) == 0L) break  # end of file
   test <- strsplit(line, " ")[[1]]
   XYN <- as.integer(test)
   X <- XYN[1]
   Y <- XYN[2]
   N <- XYN[3]
   i <- 1L
   while (i <= N) {
      is.divisible.by.X <- (i %% X) == 0L
      is.divisible.by.Y <- (i %% Y) == 0L
      out <- if (is.divisible.by.X & is.divisible.by.Y) "FB" else
             if (is.divisible.by.X) cat("F") else
             if (is.divisible.by.Y) cat("B") else as.character(i)
      cat(out, "")
      i <- i + 1L
   }
   cat("\n")
}
close(file.handle)
```

How is that different from version 1? Here we are careful to read the file and process it line-by-line instead of reading the whole file in memory. Also, when processing each line, we are careful not to generate the `seq_len(N)` vector in memory and pre-compute the output for all the values. Instead, we are counting from 1 to `N` and processing each value one at a time.

Because version 2 uses a `while` loop in place of the vectorization happening in version 1, it will be slower. But it will use a lot less memory, especially if the file contains a large number of rows or large values for `N`, both things could make version 1 fail.

I hope this helps. Let me know if you have questions.

Comment: Thank you for the solution @flodel.  I will test this code out tonight and see what the memory usage is.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve it by simply removing the assignment of

```
out <- i
```

The total improvement was from 24621056 to 1662976.

```
args <- commandArgs(trailingOnly=TRUE)
test.cases <- strsplit(readLines(args[[1]], warn=FALSE), '\n')
args <- NULL
for (test in test.cases) {
    if (length(test) > 0) {
        # ignore test if it is an empty line
        # 'test' represents the test case, do something with it
        test <- as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(test, " ")))
        x <- 0
        y <- 0
        for(i in 1: test[3]) {
            if(i != 1) cat(" ")
            flag <- TRUE
            x <- x + 1
            y <- y + 1 
            if( x == test[1] ) {
                cat("F")
                x <- 0
                flag <- FALSE
            }
            if( y == test[2] ) {
                cat("B")
                y <- 0
                flag <- FALSE
            }
            if(flag) cat(i)
        }

        cat("\n")
    }
}
```